# Android: Multiple Recycler View Inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm loading multiple `Recycler Views` inside one fragment.
The problem is None of the `Recycler Views` is working.
My Code looks like below:

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
     recyclerViewNoResult = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_home);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerViewNoResult.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                productListPageAdaptorNoView =  new ProductListPageAdaptorNoView();
                recyclerViewNoResult.setAdapter(productListPageAdaptorNoView);


     recyclerViewNoResult2 = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_home);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerViewNoResult2.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                productListPageAdaptorNoView2 =  new ProductListPageAdaptorNoView2();
                recyclerViewNoResult2.setAdapter(productListPageAdaptorNoView2);

     recyclerViewNoResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     recyclerViewNoResult2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
return rootView;
```

Comment: can you please post R.layout.fragment_main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both RecyclerView refrences are referring same `RecyclerView('R.id.recycler_view_home')` in xml. You are setting visibility to Visible and then Gone to same RecyclerView, that why nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 2):

You're using same view id for both : 'R.id.recycler_view_home'

Comment: Yep, did you try commenting out one of them?

Comment: If you want to multiple views in your layout use different ids and make views do not overlay themselves. And you are hiding one of your views without conditions. Check your adapters and post your xml layout too

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the layout programatically, to handle both of them. This does mean you'll need to also account where they'll place themselves on the view. For example 2nd Recycler sits next to the first 1. Sorry I cannot provide examples of how to do that as am currently researching that myself.

Edit: If you do as suggested by others you can do that but if you want to add more, means you would need to add more in the layout.xml of the fragments layout file. This is a static way of going about it, and might be what you're looking for but the dynamic approach in itself would serve well. For example you could fire them off in a loop based upon array size. Each would be executed to go to view in turn. To the user they're all present. Although the recyclers list would also need to be done programmatically.